# Using SessionLocaleResolver to retrieve locale information

Tags: java, spring, locale

I have included the following in my application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />


<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And in my controller class I added the following code to retrieve locale:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(Model model, HttpSession session) {

    Locale locale = (Locale) session.getAttribute( 
            SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

    return showHomePage(model, session);
}
```

Web.xml contains :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

While debugging,locale is taking null value. It should take the newly set locale value. Value that I am setting via url by passing ?lang =fr. Locale value should be set to fr but it's just giving null. Is there any other way to get the same done? Need some advise.

Comment: Don't do it like that. Use the `LocalContextHolder` to retrieve the current `Locale`. Or simply add a method argument of the type `Locale`.

Comment: Demonstrate what? if your `<mvc:interceptors /> ` is loaded in the `ContextLoaderListener` it is going to do nothing for the `DispatcherServlet` configured beans.

Comment: If you have configured everything correctly using `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` should give the current `Locale`. However as I mentioned if your `LocaleResolver` and interceptors are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and not the `DispatcherServlet` at least the interceptors, it isn't going to work.

Comment: If you are new I suggest a read of the reference guide and some tutorials. In your web.xml you can see which files are loaded by what.

Comment: I have the above two things in my web.xml file

Comment: Please don't post code as comments. Update your question. IN your config add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: sorry. i have editted please check once

Comment: is it contextloaderlistener or dispatcher servlet loading the interceptors in my case ?

Comment: Your case is a special one, due to the empty `contextConfigLocation` init parameter. So everything is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. However there are some defaults which the `DispatcherServlet` applies when certain things cannot be found. Which could render your `<mvc:interceptors />` part useless. Hence add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: Just a remark, in your controller, you can simple find the locale by adding a `Locale` parameter to your `RequestMapping` annotated methods, like `public String showUserForm(Model model, HttpSession session, Locale locale)` (at least if config make it works ...)

Comment: Thanks... I tried changing the method parameters. I am able to retrieve locale information by adding a locale parameter